# Jeditable Plugin working as it should - scope issue?

Tags: wpdb

I am using the Jeditable plugin to enable inline editing on a table inside the admin area, generated by a small plugin I've written. (http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable).
Basically everything is working, but only as long as the code for updating the database field is inside the plugin's code. As soon as I copy that code into another file and try to edit something, I get this error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function update() on a non-object in XXX
>   on line XX

I only understand partly why I get that error. Is it because $wpdb is not initialized? I tried global $wpdb without luck. That's why I think I am missing something, somewhere in the code $wpdb gets "lost" somehow, so the update method can't be found.
It is really frustrating, because the code is working, but as soon as I use it in a seperate file, it's not working. If needed I can post the code, but I am hoping it's just a standard issue.

EDIT: Ok, so here is my code:

That is the Jeditable plugin in action, right after the table (Let's say it's inside the index.php):

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('.edit').editable('../wp-content/plugins/myplugin/save.php', {
            indicator   :   'Saving...',
            tooltip     :   'Please click to edit!',
            id          :   'my_id',
            name        :   'my_value',
            width       :   'none',
            cssclass    :   'editable-input'
        });
    });
</script>
```

As you can see, I am calling the save.php which looks like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['my_id']))
{
    error_reporting (E_ALL);

    $explode    =   explode('-', $_POST['my_id']);
    $my_row =   $explode[0];
    $my_id      =   $explode[1];
    $my_value   =   $_POST['ck_value'];

    if($my_row == 'date') {

        $exp = explode(' ', $my_value);

        switch($exp[1]) {
            case 'Jan': case 'jan': case 'Januar': case 'januar': case '01': case '1':
                $month = '01';
                $montha = 'Jan';
                break;
            case 'Feb': case 'feb': case 'Februar': case 'februar': case '02': case '2':
                $month = '02';
                $montha = 'Feb';
                break;
        }


        $day = substr($exp[0], 0, 2);
        $wpdb->update($table_name, array('ck_date' => $exp[2].'-'.$month.'-'.$day, 'ck_monthabbr' => $montha) , array('ck_id' => $my_id));
        echo $exp[2].'-'.$month.'-'.$day.'<br />';
    }

    if($my_row == 'ogo') {
        $wpdb->update($table_name, array('ck_geo' => $my_value) , array('ck_id' => $my_id));
    }

    if($my_row == 'vue') {
        $wpdb->update($table_name, array('ck_venue' => $my_value) , array('ck_id' => $my_id));
    }
}
```

Inside the index.php, I have global $wpdb and $table_name defined, but save.php doesn't recognize these variables.

Comment: I do believe we may need to see your code, although somebody else may be able to answer it. (?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you will need to include some type of WP core file into the `save.php` file (I could be wrong). Since this file isn't being called specifically by your plugin (or WP for that matter), it won't have all of the variables that WP has to offer.

Try adding this to the top of your `save.php` file:

```
require_once '../../../../wp-load.php';
```

There may be better ways to get the URL, and even maybe a better file to use than `wp-load.php`, but at least to verify it works that way will probably relieve some stress.

You may also want to use `global $wpdb;` in `save.php` after `wp-load.php` is included.

Comment: Sorry to disappoint you, it's still not working.

Comment: @Sven The issue is that your save.php file doesn't know what $wpdb is. We can at least conclude that it is a scope issue. Possibly the URL to wp-load.php is going back too far or not far enough? Just a thought, and could be a possibility.

Comment: Ok, got it working, thank you! wp-blog-header.php is the file that needs to be included and I was working in the wrong file. Well, I am a beginner ;-)

Comment: We all start somewhere :) Glad you got it figured out!

Comment: More importantly, instead of `include` you may want to use `require_once`. To quote the PHP manual, "`include()` produces a Warning while `require()` results in a Fatal Error. Fatal errors stop script execution." Source: http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Coding_Standards#include_once_vs_require_once